# Expand category in a column to column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to expand (not sure if it is the right word) some categorical 
data into columns using pandas.

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'name': ['john', 'john', 'louis', 'louis'], 
                       'day':['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], 'oranges':[10, 23, 15, 5],
                       'apple': [5, 4, 1, 3]})
```

Which produces this table:

```
       apple day   name  oranges
    0       5  a   john       10
    1       4  b   john       23
    2       1  a   louis      15
    3       3  b   louis       5
```

I would like to use some pandas method to produce a table like this:

```
   apple_a apple_b name  oranges_a  oranges_b
 0       5       4  john         10         23
 1       1       3  louis        15          5
```

So far I've tried:

```
df.pivot('name', columns='day')

       apple        oranges
   day        a  b        a   b
   name
   john       5  4        10  23
   louis      1  3        15   5
```

My question is: how can I split my data and create more columns based on a categorical information using Pandas?

Thanks in advance,

Rhenan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already got the desired output, you need to format the column names

```
df = df.pivot('name', columns='day')
df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
df = df.reset_index()

    name    apple_a apple_b oranges_a   oranges_b
0   john    5       4       10          23
1   louis   1       3       15          5
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try using `set_index`, `stack`, `unstack` then mapping that multiindex columns to a signle level using `map` and `join`:

```
df.set_index(['name','day']).stack().unstack([2,1])
df_1.columns = df_1.columns.map('_'.join)
print(df_1)
```

Output:

```
       apple_a  oranges_a  apple_b  oranges_b
name                                         
john         5         10        4         23
louis        1         15        3          5
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you all very much!
Based on your answers I've got a code that does the trick:

```
n_df = df.pivot('name', columns='day')
n_df.columns = n_df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Output:

```
       apple_a  apple_b  oranges_a  oranges_b
  name
  john       5        4         10         23
  louis      1        3         15          5
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Why not take the best from both solutions?  +1

Comment: Great that it worked for you, don't forget to accept an answer. @ScottBoston's solution of mapping multiindex columns to single level is far superior so I would go with that.